# For loop in batch issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I'm attempting to rewrite an .sh script to a .bat file so that I can test it on Windows VM.

I have encountered an issue with FOR /F loop, I am unable to use the variables I set in the loop, I'm really frustrated about this. I have been looking around for a while and I have enabled delayed expansion, to no luck. Below is the piece of code :

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=, " %%i in (%SOutPath%) do (

SET sKic1Length = 20
SET sRAMTar = %%i
SET admCode = %%j
SET pin1Code = %%k
SET pin2Code = %%l
SET sKic1 = %%m
SET sKic1Length = %%n
SET sKid1 = %%o
SET sKid1Length = %%p
SET sRAMMSL=%%r

IF sKic1Length EQU 16 SET sKic1Length=11
IF sKic1Length EQU 32 SET sKic1Length=15
IF sKic1Length EQU 48 SET sKic1Length=19
::This echo outputs 'Echo is off' so variable is empty
@echo %sKic1Length%  

)
::Also returns same
ECHO %sKid1Length%
```

Below is the file that I'm reading in the loop :

```
; ;, RAMTAR, ADM1, PIN1, PIN2, KIC1, KICLENGTH,KID1, KIDLENGTH, RAMMSL
000000, 17182320, 2387, 1116, 607038CA34A91FB1, 16, 607038CA34A91FB, 16, 0200
```

I would appreciate any input.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ! instead of % on ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in a loop

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=, " %%i in (%SOutPath%) do (
    set "sKic1Length=20"
    set "sRAMTar=%%i"
    set "admCode=%%j"
    set "pin1Code=%%k"
    set "pin2Code=%%l"
    set "sKic1=%%m"
    set "sKic1Length=%%n"
    set "sKid1=%%o"
    set "sKid1Length=%%p"
    set "sRAMMSL=%%r"
    if "!sKic1Length!" equ "16" set "sKic1Length=11"
    if "!sKic1Length!" equ "32" set "sKic1Length=15"
    if "!sKic1Length!" equ "48" set "sKic1Length=19"
    echo.!sKic1Length!
)
echo.%sKid1Length% 
endlocal
```

If the last echo returns nothing, then I assume, that in the  last iteration %%p was empty.